# Trying to make a paragraph break in a flash message with \n not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, alerts

I've been trying to make a paragraph in this little piece of code:

```
flash[:error] = "ATENÇÃO!\nNenhum dos campos pode ser deixado em branco"
```

right where the \n is, but when I render it on my ruby application it doesn't seem to make a paragraph any help/ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use `\n` and handle the break with CSS, like this:

**erb**

```
<div class="new-line"><%= flash[:error] %></div>
```

**style**

```
<style type="text/css">
  .new-line {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
  }
</style>
```

With that styling in place, `\n` will behave as `<br>`.

Comment: did it like this: `<% if flash[:error] %>
<div class="jumbotron2">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="error">
    <%= flash[:error] %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<% end %>
`

`.error {
 white-space: pre-wrap;
}`

Comment: @xdmanmagiconsei That should work, just don't forget to put `.error { ... }` on a stylesheet or between `<style></style>` tags.

Comment: Nvm I put it in the wrong controller, it's working now! thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In HTML you need `<br />`

```
"ATENÇÃO!<br />Nenhum dos campos pode ser deixado em branco"
```

And render your flash message like

```
flash[:error].html_safe
```

Comment: Still doesn't do the break, when I rendered it it showed the <br /> as text

Comment: Have you called `html_safe` at the end?

Comment: yes, I did, I copied what you posted and put it there

Comment: Mmm, it looks strange to me :/

Comment: It's a controller file so it can't be .html.erb and in ruby you use \n to do the break but it doesn't  render it

Comment: Well, you are in a ruby file but in the end that string is used in an HTML template

Comment: I suspect that the `html_safe` flag doesn't make it through the session. Try calling `html_safe` when rendering the flash message (or alternatively [`simple_format`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-simple_format)).

Comment: I wanted to suggest that too